# simulate key board input does not work

Tags: java, c++, selenium

I have a web tag as such:

```
<object tabindex="2" class ="commentClass" id="_comment_1491528136824_10" classid="CLSID:0CBFD428-E975-4B41-A8C6-EB820FA5BDE6" onkeydown="if(13==event.keyCode || 27==event.keyCode)commentGuardCtrl('_comment_container_1491528136824_10',0);">
    <param name = "input2" value = "[\s\S]*"/>
    <param name = "kbmode" value = "1"/>
    <param name = "maxlength" value = "12"/>
    <param name = "input3" value = "^[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_{|}~]{6,12}$"/>
</object>
```

I want to automatically enter text into this element, however regardless I use Java Selenium library or JNI C++ to simulate keyboard input, text can never go to this field. Selenium library or JNI C++ keyboard simulation code works fine in other html elements, but not this one.

Can you gurus help me out? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you put how you select this element?

Comment: Unable to select this element by Selenium library, I used TAB key to move focus.

Comment: Which particular field you want to enter to?

Comment: This object element is displayed as a text input field in IE browser, I don't know how it works

Comment: This element can be found by:WebElement userPwd = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(...));

Comment: Please include some code that you have tried. You're more likely to get better answers if others can see that you have at least tried to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: How does this whole <object> appear on your screen?

Comment: Kushal, I don't know how <object> element appeared in IE browser.

Comment: @To Yep_It's_me:WebElement userLog = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".bannerlogin.log .logctrl .logClass"));
userLog.click();
userLog.sendKeys("xyz");  //xyz did not go to the <object>, but I could manually enter text into <object>

Comment: having done some research, I would probably need to use winio64.dll to simulate keyboard strikes, however unable to find the tutorial of winio64.dll, any one has some winio64.dll tutorial?

Comment: "Unable to select this `element` by Selenium library". I've never run into that scenario before. Even if it's complicated, you can almost always construct a reliable selector to get the `element` you want, or at least a pretty good one. It seems you're on a wild goose chase trying to find a way around just getting the `element` you want. If you edit your question to add more of the `html`, for the element you want to click, and any related elements to help you find that element, you might get some help with that.

Comment: Additionally, trying to run tests with keyboard commands sounds like a pretty good way to make your tests unreliable and difficult for anybody to understand what it's really doing in the future! Let me know if you want some help with a selector :)

Comment: @mrfreester: I am able to find the element after some effort. but I have done lots of research & test, unable to enter text into it.

Comment: @Charlie good progress. If you can't enter text into a control, and the control is enabled, it usually means the element you're trying to enter text into isn't the right one. It might be in the same location on the page, but it's not the actual text input. You have to get the exact right element in the dom. Best of luck!

Comment: WebElement comment = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".banner.log.logwordctrl .commentClass"));   comment.sendKeys("xyz");  This code did not send "xyz" to the object control-HTML element. variable comment was not null, but nothing was input into it.

Comment: I have solved this problem by C++/JNI technology. The key points: 1.) Load WInIO64.sys, start WinIO service 2.) SetPortVal()